# In java, when does object space die out, which is created by "new" operator

Tags: java

I write Java program, and I wanna get clear with some memory management in Java.
For example, a method like this:

```
 public void example1() {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[100];
    }
```

after calling this method, does the byte[] space created by "new" in Heap space die out?
The 2th example like this:

```
public byte[] example2() {
       byte[] bytes = new byte[100];
       return bytes
}
```

also the question, does the byte[] space die out in this situation?

Comment: In Java, anything that you allocate with `new` is placed on the heap. Whenever the Java garbage collector runs (which is whenever Java decides it should), it checks to see if any objects are not referenced by anywhere in the program (= can never be referenced again ever), and frees their memory if so.

Comment: Objects in java are created by using new keyword, are stored on heap.The garbage collector collect those objects when there is no reference for those objects remains.

Comment: @JDeveloper - it is more complicated than that ...

Comment: when the GC runs it only marks objects that have no ref at first. GC is expensive. when it runs again if it sees that mem being used is more then available then it might take clear some objects. what if you have 20GB RAM as your min memory and your program is only using 5GB? then it wont de allocate. read about GC pause, parallel GC, etc in google

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The space is *garbage collected* when the garbage collector runs and it detects that there are no more references to it. In this case if this is the only code concerned the reference ceases to exist when the method exits, so the space is *eligible* for collection from then onwards.

Answer (score 1):

For your first example:

```
public void example1() {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[100];
}
```

[image]

When the method exits, all references to the object created within the method are gone, so it's eligible for "destruction" by the garbage collector.

[image]

In your second example:

```
public byte[] example2() {
       byte[] bytes = new byte[100];
       return bytes
}
```

Here, you're returning the value. And if you're using that returned value somewhere, for example, `byte[] myByte = example2();`, an active reference is retained, thus the object won't be available for collection.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You as Java programmer can not force Garbage collection in Java; it will only trigger if JVM thinks it needs a garbage collection based on Java heap size. garbage collector runs and it detects that there are no more references to it.

[**SEE HERE**](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2011/04/garbage-collection-in-java.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
public void example1() {
    byte[] bytes = new byte[100];
}
```

The object referred to by `bytes` variable will be eligible for garbage collection, after the completion of the `example1()` method because, the only active reference it had in the form of the local variable `bytes` will be purged from the function call stack.

```
public byte[] example2() {
   byte[] bytes = new byte[100];
   return bytes
}
```

Here the object referred to by `bytes` will not be eligible for garbage collection immediately after the end of the `example2()` method because you are returning the reference. So, if you had something like this `byte[] returnedRef = example2()`.  Then the reference is now held by the variable `returnRef`  even after the local method variable `bytes` is purged from the function call stack. So until and unless that reference held by `returnedRef` is detached either by making 1) `returnedRef=null` or 2)if `returnedRef` is a local variable, then at the end of the method where `returnedRef` is defined, it will be purged , the object will not be eligible for garbage collection.

Again even if an object is eligible for Garbage Collection doesn't necessarily mean it will be destroyed by the GC. When the garbage collector will run is best left to JVM to decide.

Answer (score 0):

In general, it is not possible to say with certainty when an object's space will "die"; i.e. when the memory used to represent it will be reclaimed.  All you can say with certainty is that:

- The space won't be reclaimed while anything can still *possibly* use the object; i.e. while it is still *reachable*.
- If the object is *unreachable*, it will be reclaimed before the JVM gets to a point where it has to tell the application that it has run out of memory.

The good news is that you don't need to worry about *when* reclamation happens.  If it can happen, it will happen before it causes trouble.

The bad news (sort of) is that since you can't predict when an object will be reclaimed, it is a bad idea to write code that depends on the timing; e.g. by depending on `finalize` methods being run in a timely fashion.

---

In your first example, the `byte[]` is *eligible* to be garbage collected when the method returns.  In the second example, we can't say anything at all.  It depends on what the caller does with the returned value.